# Passing more than one value of same kind in same hidden variable in struts2

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, struts

At the outset, i am using struts2, java and javascript to get my job done. I have outlined the problem as follows.

I have the following table on my page -

```
___________________________
checkbox  |  phone  | Name      
---------------------------
   []     | 123-456 | abcde

   []     | 234-567 | testname
____________________________
```

(It is an outline, but stay with me)

The code for the table is as follows:

```html
<s:if test="reportFilter.huntGroups!=null && reportFilter.huntGroups.size()>0">
    <s:iterator var="huntGroupVO" value="reportFilter.huntGroups" status="huntGroupKey">
      <tr <s:if test="#huntGroupKey.odd">class="oddRows"</s:if>>
        <td width="40px"><s:checkbox id="specHg_checkbox_%{#huntGroupKey.index}" name="reportFilter.selectedHuntGroups"  fieldValue="%{#huntGroupVO.phoneNumber}" value="%{reportFilter.selectedHuntGroups!=null && reportFilter.selectedHuntGroups.contains(#huntGroupVO.phoneNumber)?true:false}" theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
      <td>
        <s:if test="#huntGroupVO.phoneNumber.length()>0">
          <s:property value="#huntGroupVO.phoneNumber"/>
        </s:if>
        <s:else>
          <s:property value="#huntGroupVO.userGroupId"/>
        </s:else>
      </td>

      <td class="hntName"><s:property value="#huntGroupVO.name"></s:property></td>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

As is evident, i am passing the phone number as value when i tick the check-box. 
The problem is, i want to pass the name too.

I understand that we can pass it along with the phone number using something like a hyphen.

Assuming i have another variable `ArrayList<String> hiddenName` , i would like to populate the names corresponding to the ticked checkboxes in this variable. (I am thinking via a `s:hidden` parameter)

I apologize if it sounds a little confusing, but please help!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can only pass a single value in any given form field.

You have a number of options, from the simple–use a string and split it to get both values, through the middle–pass an ID and retrieve the appropriate values in Java, to the complex–custom type conversion.

Which makes the most sense depends a lot on where your data is, *how* your data is, and so on.

---

Unrelated, but I find that JSP very difficult to read. I would refactor a significant amount. The following is untested, but much closer to what I would expect after a code review.

```html
<s:if test="reportFilter.showGroups">
  <s:iterator value="reportFilter.huntGroups" status="status">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <s:checkbox id="specHg_checkbox_%{#status.index}" theme="simple"
                    name="reportFilter.selectedHuntGroups" 
                    fieldValue="phoneNumber" 
                    value="%{reportFilter.hasNumber(phoneNumber)}" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <s:set var="num" value="${phoneNumber.length() > 0 ? phoneNumber : userGroupId" />
        <s:property value="#num"/>
      </td>

      <td class="hntName"><s:property value="name"/></td>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

A few things of note:

- Logic to decide if we'll show groups encapsulated in Java. Makes testing easier, too.
- Reasonable, shorter name for the iteration object: it's a group (or huntGroup).
- Extract the (phone number || group ID) value, eliminating a bunch of JSP tags.
- (Ideally that logic would be hidden in Java, either in the VO, or a decorator.)
- The iterator tag pushes the iteration object onto the value stack, eliminating the need for directly referencing it by name. This one is a bit more iffy; it depends on your needs.
- In real life I'd probably put the entire group thing into a separate JSP or custom tag.